# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'update_settings' scrapy 1.0.5

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, attributeerror

The crawler works fine by command line by gives this error:

```
2016-03-30 03:47:59 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: scrapybot)
2016-03-30 03:47:59 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-03-30 03:47:59 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ahmeds/scrapProject/crawler/startcrawls.py", line 11, in <module>
    process.crawl(onioncrawl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 150, in crawl
    crawler = self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 166, in _create_crawler
    return Crawler(spidercls, self.settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.spidercls.update_settings(self.settings)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'update_settings'
```

This is my code for running my crawler by script as per [latest documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html). My scrapy version is 1.0.5.

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from crawler.spiders import onioncrawl

setting = get_project_settings()
process = CrawlerProcess(setting)
process.crawl(onioncrawl)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 18):

I was using Spider filename instead of Spider class name.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
process.crawl(onioncrawl.<ClassName>).
```

Replace the ClassName with the real class name in your onioncrawl module

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue with Python 2.7.x and Scrapy 1.7.x

below line of code fixed my issue

```
process.crawl(onioncrawl.ClassName)
```

Answer (score 1):

while using py3, if project structure like this

```
crawler
----spiders
--------onioncrawl.py(class onioncrawl defined in this file)
```

try `from crawler.spiders.onioncrawl import onioncrawl` and `process.crawl(onioncrawl)`.